# RHEL7 - very long start times on JRE

Tags: rhel, java, openjdk

I'm using RHEL7, and I've ran into problems with Pycharm where it takes a *very* long time to start, a few minutes. According to the logs, it's mostly waiting for the JRE/JVM to start. So I tried to focus on getting Java to start faster, and that seems to have issues starting in other situations as well. I tried just getting the version, and even that would take a long time (although not the second time immediately after, when it was in memory):

```bsh
[wile_e8@wile_e82 wile_e8]$ time java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_292"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_292-b10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.292-b10, mixed mode)

real    0m41.814s
user    0m0.039s
sys     0m0.020s
[wile_e8@wile_e82 wile_e8]$ time java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_292"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_292-b10) 
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.292-b10, mixed mode)

real    0m0.076s
user    0m0.047s
sys     0m0.027s
```

So when it isn't already in memory, it takes 41 seconds for the JRE to start up just to print the version. This is a relatively new computer. Is this just a memory thing, or is there something I could change with the JRE configuration so Java programs start faster?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related to the bug [**JDK-4705093**](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4705093) when generating `SecureRandom` for `SHA1PRNG`.

```bsh
# it's not obvious, but it also happens..
```

**Solution:** for system-wide Java

1. Open the file

   ```
   $JAVA_PATH/jre/lib/security/java.security
   ```
2. Find the line

   ```
   securerandom.source=file:/dev/random
   ```
3. Replace it with the line

   ```
   securerandom.source=file:/dev/./urandom
   ```

**Addition:** Pycharm has its own `JBR`. Try the same with this file:

```
$PYCHARM_FOLDER/jbr/conf/security/java.security
```

---

<sup>A more detailed description of the error: [«Tomcat7 starts too late on Ubuntu 14.04 x64»](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26432537/8280225).</sup>

Comment: I actually found that Tomcat7 description on my search for a solution before, that didn't solve the problem. But I gave it a try again:

`
    [acyakli@acyakli2 security]$ sudoedit java.security
    [sudo] password for acyakli: 
    [acyakli@acyakli2 security]$ time java -version
    openjdk version "1.8.0_292"
    OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_292-b10)
    OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.292-b10, mixed mode)
    
    real 0m42.810s
    user 0m0.042s
    sys 0m0.028s
`

So that's not the problem.

Comment: But this is happening for _all_ Java programs, Pycharm is just where I run into it the most. The tests I'm running are with the regular OpenJDK java, and it's taking >40s to print the version.

But I did try modifying the Pycharm version of java.security, and it didn't help.